# How create tgz archive file in windows?

Tags: zip, gzip, tar

How can I create myData.tgz in Windows?
I need my data in tgz Archiv format in windows 10
but I dont know how can ?
I know how create tar.gz Archiv,but .tgz I dont know

Answer (score 1):

tgz is simply a different spelling for tar.gz. If you rename your file.tar.gz to file.tgz, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the same procedure as in Linux Environment using CMD, PowerShell, or Git Bash, etc...

Compression using **tar**:

```
tar -cvzf <name of tarball>.tgz path/to/source/folder
```

for example, the command to compress a folder sample in my current directory to a file **backup.tgz**:

```
tar -cvzf backup.tgz sample
```

For more refer to the documentation of tar command